# Django Testing - SimpleCookie and Session

Tags: django, django-testing

**Problem**: My testing client appears to log out once i attempt to set a cookie. I have workspace (project) object that i want my client to access. The access itself works fine, but as soon as i attempt to edit cookies in my session, the client gets logged out. My test is documented below.

**Code**

```
import time
from http.cookies import SimpleCookie

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test import Client, TestCase
from django.urls import reverse
from myproject.models import DataSource, Workspace


class TestSomeStuff(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        datasource1, _ = DataSource.objects.update_or_create(id=1, defaults=dict(source_name="Source 1"))

        workspace1, _ = Workspace.objects.get_or_create(id=1, defaults=dict(project_name="Project 1",
                                                                            datasource=datasource1))
        self.workspace_view_url = reverse("workspace", args=[workspace1.id])
        self.client = Client()
        print(self.client.get(self.workspace_view_url))  # 302 - redirect to login page as expected
        self.client.force_login(User.objects.get_or_create(username='testuser')[0])
        print(self.client.get(self.workspace_view_url))  # 200 - as expected
        time.sleep(2)
        print(self.client.get(self.workspace_view_url))  # 200 - as expected
        time.sleep(2)
        self.client.cookies = SimpleCookie()
        print(self.client.get(self.workspace_view_url))  # 302 - why?

    def test_my_test(self):
        pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `self.client.cookies = SimpleCookie()` wipes all cookies - including the 'sessionid' and 'csrftoken'. I changed it to `self.client.cookies["cookie_key"] = "cookie_value"`